# Force users to select a file with PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm new to PySimpleGui and I've searched every recipe for something that may help me and came up empty handed.

What I'm trying to do is: User will select a file, click a button and the app will do something with the file. This is what I have so far:

```
layout = [[sg.Text('Sistema'), sg.InputText(key='-file1-'), sg.FileBrowse()], [sg.Button("Go")]]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event == "Go":
            *do something with file1*
```

What I want is:

```
layout = [[sg.Text('Sistema'), sg.InputText(key='-file1-'), sg.FileBrowse()], [sg.Button("Go")]]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if values["-file1-"] == "": 
            print("You need to choose a file!")
            *allow users to select a new file without closing the window*

        if event == "Go":
            *do something with file1*
```

What do I need to do? If I add a break statement, it leaves the while loop and closes the window. I need it to allow users to select a new file and read the window again. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm filename OK or not when event `Go` in event loop.

Here, `Cancel` to cancel selection of a file, also stop `Go`.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Sistema'), sg.InputText(key='-file1-'), sg.FileBrowse()],
    [sg.Button("Go")],
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Go":
        filename = values['-file1-']
        while True:
            if not Path(filename).is_file():
                if filename == '':
                    sg.popup_ok('Select a file to go !')
                else:
                    sg.popup_ok('File not exist !')
                filename = sg.popup_get_file("", no_window=True)
                if filename == '':
                    break
                window['-file1-'].update(filename)
            else:
                print('File is ready !')
                break

window.close()
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!